# How to launch another app from my Ubuntu Touch app?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I want to have a button in a Ubuntu Touch app I'm planning to create which will launch another app (say camera-app). How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the Url dispatcher:https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/platform/guides/url-dispatcher-guide/

You can put these urls in the code just like you were going to open other urls/external websites.

For example, I can use this to call the terminal like:

```
appid://com.ubuntu.terminal/terminal/current-user-version
```

But, if since you say the camera I assume you may want to use the picture it takes in some way instead of just launching the app, In this case you should look into the content hub: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/platform/guides/content-hub-guide/